# ip6tables TPROXY not working

Tags: ipv6, rhel6

I have a problem, I need to have to run a java program on a port < 1024. authbind and jsvc are no alternatives, it is simply decided not to use.

But using

```
 ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING  -p udp --dport 546 -j TPROXY --on-port 8547
```

gives me

```
ip6tables v1.4.7: unknown option `--on-port'
```

What did I miss?

```
uname -a
 Linux vieppetat12 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 1 01:33:01 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64  x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 TPROXY support was [added in RHEL 6.1](http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2011-0542.html). You are running 6.0 for some reason (and shouldn't be).

To resolve the issue, register your system and then fully update it.

```
yum --obsoletes update
```